# Is there a program out there that will give you details for paying X extra per month?

Tags: calculation, debt, student-loan, debt-reduction

I've got about 6 loans or so with different payoff times and interest rates. My general strategy is to calculate how much I'd save by paying an extra X per month, always directed towards the loan with the highest interest rate.

However, calculating this is tough by hand because you have to figure out when loan 1 is paid off, then roll the other loans forward to that date, repeat the process, etc, and sometimes certain low-interest loans get paid off naturally before you can reach them to apply +X to it per month, and so on.

Is there anything out there that takes all this into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably interested in doing is a variant of the [Debt-snowball method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debt-snowball_method) of paying down your debt.  For an online calculator using a method like what you described, check out **[Snowball debt calculator](http://www.whatsthecost.com/snowball.aspx)**.  Here's the description from the site itself:

> Snowballing is all about paying your debts in the correct order.
>   Generally speaking you should **attempt to pay off the debts with the
>   highest interest rate first**. Some people, such as Dave Ramsey suggest
>   you pay the card with the smallest balance first, that's fine, and can
>   help you feel you're getting rid of the debt quicker, but it's not the
>   most efficient way. This calculator allows you to **enter up to 20
>   different debts** with their associated APRs, and the **total amount you
>   want to spend per month servicing your debts**, and it'll work out the
>   order in which you should pay them together with the monthly payments.
>   [...]   *[emphasis mine]*

The tool appears to do what you are looking for.

Note:  The site is in the U.K. and the currency symbol shown is '£', but if you ignore that and look at numbers only, it ought to calculate reasonable results for other countries.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and best option is to create an Excel Spreadsheet to do this for you. I'm sure there are a few budget apps that would do this for you, but their cost is usually too high and they aren't as flexible as a custom Excel Spreadsheet.

Excel includes a Loan Payoff template that you can use as a starter.